# MySQL: find MAX(var1) but return var2 of that entry instead

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a table (or rather a long join) with fields (id, name, prio) where I group over id

```
SELECT id, group_concat(name)
FROM my_table
GROUP BY id
```

Now I'd also like to have a column with the name of the lowest prio score. Like

```
SELECT id, group_concat(name), min(prio)
FROM my_table
GROUP BY id
```

but instead of having the minimum value of prio I'd like to see the corresponding 'name'

Any idea?

Comment: Did either of the answers below help you? Please accept/comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can make this a sub-query and then join it to the table something like:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT id, group_concat(name), min(prio) AS lowest
        FROM my_table
    GROUP BY id ) foo
JOIN my_table mt ON foo.lowest = mt.prio AND foo.id=mt.id;
```

Comment: I tried your approach. However, as I used it within more nested SELECTs it turned out quite slow in the end (I have long tables). Maybe subselects have no indices and thus are slow? For the moment I use a hybrid approach with GROUP_CONCAT and a Python module doing the prio selection.

Comment: This method will be quite slow as (unlike with JOIN queries, etc) MySQL's optimiser is unable to optimise sub-queries like this. Instead it runs the deepest nested sub-queries first and then works its way up.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do it in one select , use joined select

```
SELECT a.id, ..., b.name FROM my_table JOIN ( SELECT id, name FROM my_table ORDER BY prio ASC LIMIT 1 ) AS b ON b.id = a.id ...
```